# Ubuntu 18.04 detects WiFi but gives connection error when trying to connect, please help!

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

My Ubuntu 18.04 is dual-booted with Windows 10 on an Acer One Z1402. I've only set up the OS yesterday, and it has never connected to the WiFi ever since. Ubuntu *does* detect the WiFi connection, but gives a Connection error when trying to connect to it.

I know the error is not because of the WiFi or the laptop itself, since it connects to the WiFi just fine when running Windows. I've tried mounting the ubuntu .iso file as a virtual CD to try install additional drivers, but that didn't work since it displays "No additional drivers found."

Please help me try to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

**EDIT 1:** I forgot to add in info about the WiFi drivers. This is what's displayed when running `lspci -v`:

```
Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
Subsystem: Device 1d05:1011
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
Memory at aa014000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at aa014000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

Answer (score 0):

I've googled and found this: 
[ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359516)

You've got a driver that is not supported by Ubuntu by default. Try to follow their advice. Some companies such as Realtek or Broadcom do not have open drivers. Some have been reversed engineered, some may run with a ndis wrapper. (Look it up). Good luck!